# Messages lost through netty channels if handlers are added asynchronously

Tags: scala, netty, future

I have observed that if I don't put a handler immediately once the callback is received, I loose out on messages for eg:

**Works**

```scala
    new jChannel.ChannelInitializer[jChannel.socket.SocketChannel] {
        override def initChannel(ch: jChannel.socket.SocketChannel): Unit = {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new jHttp.HttpServerCodec())
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new jHttp.HttpObjectAggregator(64))
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyCustomRequestHandler)
        }
    }
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
    new jChannel.ChannelInitializer[jChannel.socket.SocketChannel] {
        override def initChannel(ch: jChannel.socket.SocketChannel): Unit = Future { // Async Handling
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new jHttp.HttpServerCodec())
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new jHttp.HttpObjectAggregator(64))
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyCustomRequestHandler)
        }
    }
```

What should I do to make sure that I can attach listeners asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want to do by setting `ChannelOption.AUTO_READ` to `false` and then setting it to `true` one you added the handlers you want.

Can you specify these options during bootstrap for example

Comment: This worked pretty well! I couldn't find any reasonable documentation suggesting this anywhere though.

Comment: It seems like this option doesn't work with client channels?

Comment: it should ... if it does not please open a bug report in our issue tracker.